# How to generate different logs for different applications hosted on same Payara server

Tags: logging, glassfish, webserver, client-server, hosting

I have hosted 2 applications on same Payara server as we do on server console under "Applications" tab in http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf.

Is it possible to generate log files differently for both applications?

Currently logs are generated at "C:\payara-4.1.1.162\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs" and when we deploy applications it comes under path "C:\payara-4.1.1.162\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications" so there is literally common folder "logs" for all applications deployed.

Please let me know about it. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

If you create another instance on the same server and deploy each applications to different instances, it's possible.

For example, create a new node named "node1" and a new instance named "server1" on "node1". (Remember run "server1" after create it.) Then deploy the first application to "server" (the default node) and the second to "server2". It's easier to use the admin console than asadmin.

This result seems following;

- The log for "server" with the first application is out to "C:\payara-4.1.1.162\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs"
- The log for "server1" with the second application is out to "C:\payara-4.1.1.162\payara41\glassfish\nodes\localhost-domain1\server1\logs"

The paths can be changed to modify their logging configurations.

Comment: Thanks man, I figured that out.

I have hosted website on Stand-alone instance in Payara admin console. When I launched this application from "Applications" tab then it does open properly but when I am not on server machine and try to open it from my computer or any other computer, it doesn't open.
Same website if I host/deploy on default "server (Admin Server)" , it works properly.

I am suspecting it could be an issue of Node which I have used to create "Stand alone instance". I created node of type "CONFIG".

IDK whats wrong, are you aware of it?

Comment: Would you check the port numbers of two instances? (In the default, Admin Server is 8080 and another one is 28080.)

Comment: Yaah, I checked port numbers and it looks fine. I got to know that this is some firewall issue which was preventing this port number because server is managed by my school so they restricted it... Thanks